# Fill a datatable with a JSON (api) in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, datatable

JSON example :

```
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "completed": false
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
        "completed": false
    }
[...]
link : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos
```

I need to create automaticly fill datatable with javascript (without jQuery) and without printing html (like printing  in the script). The JSON is sent by an API with a get request. I think we need a premise and passing by the dom. Sorry I'm a beginner in JS

What I tried (not for the same example)

```
const selectUsers = document.querySelector('select#users');
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(function(response) {
     return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(users) {
     users.forEach(function(user) {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = user.name;
        selectUsers.add(option);
     });
  });
```

Comment: Yes I'm french x)

Comment: Please provide some exaples of what you have tried and it might be easier to help you along.

Comment: I added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly more universal form of doing the same would be this:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(r=>r.json()).then(D=>
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = 
      "<thead><tr><th>"+Object.keys(D[0]).join("</th><th>")+"</th></tr></thead>\n<tbody>"
      +D.map(d=>"<tr><td>"+Object.values(d).join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>").join("\n")+"</tbofy></table>"
  );
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

In my snippet I put "everything" I find in an object into the table and the table header (´`)  is also generated on the basis of the properties found.

Answer (score 1):

here an example for add table to html with JS

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    const dataTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
    data.forEach(function(data) {
      const row = dataTable.insertRow(1);
      const title = row.insertCell(0);
      const completed = row.insertCell(1);
      title.innerHTML = data.title;
      completed.innerHTML = data.completed;
    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table id="myTable" class="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>completed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```